# Sprites not showing on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have a tile based platform game where the tiles are currently rendered in coloured rectangles using the fillRect function. I have a spritesheet which i want to use to render the rectangles instead. Each tile and sprite is 32pixels in width and height. I know i need a load function when croping an image but im not sure where it should go as i need to crop and draw the sprites 60 frames a second. Heres my js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/LsLpyn8p/4/

Or the code below:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var width = 6;
    var height = 3;
    var tileSize = 32;

    var counter = 0;
    var playerUp = false;

    setInterval(gameLoop, 1000 / 30);

    function gameLoop() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                posX = (x * tileSize) + 1 * x;
                posY = (y * tileSize) + 1 * y;

                //     ctx.fillStyle = "green";
                //   ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, tileSize, tileSize);
                var spriteSheet = new Image();
                spriteSheet.src = 'https://pasteboard.co/GMAwgYX.png';

                ctx.drawImage(spriteSheet, 0, 4 * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize, posX, posY, tileSize, tileSize);
            }
        }

        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(50, counter, tileSize, tileSize);

        if (playerUp == true) {
            counter--;
        } else {
            counter++;
        }

        if (counter == 100) {
            playerUp = true;
        } else if (counter == 0) {
            playerUp = false;
        }
    }
```

Any help is appricated thanks

Comment: your .src links to HTML not IMG https://ibb.co/e5K5Qb

Comment: oops i needed an online on for fiddle, its a png now but its still not working

Comment: You need change image url to `https://image.ibb.co/hZe5Qb/levelOne.png` and then attention : image is loading asynchronously, so when you try to draw it, image actually is not loaded yet

Comment: your math is wrong https://jsfiddle.net/LsLpyn8p/5/ try this: `ctx.drawImage(spriteSheet, 0, 10, tileSize, tileSize, posX, posY, tileSize, tileSize);`

Comment: but if im cropping the image 60 times a second, its not going to have chance loading before i need to use it again

Comment: @SlavikRibz, once image is loaded to memory it will not be loaded anymore. And you need to wait only first loading

Comment: ah i see now thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are attempting to place a cut-out-piece of an image.

you are pointing to `4 * tileSize`, in this case it's 4*32 = 128.

The X coordinate of your SourceImage is 128. The image is too small and does not have this many pixels.

Start with `10`, for example:

```
ctx.drawImage(spriteSheet, 0, 10, tileSize, tileSize, posX, posY, tileSize, tileSize);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LsLpyn8p/5/)

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

```
void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);

sx
The X coordinate of the top left corner of the sub-rectangle of the source image to draw into the destination context.

sy
The Y coordinate of the top left corner of the sub-rectangle of the source image to draw into the destination context.
```